# How to get the data that is stored in ArrayList from another class in Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I'm new in Java/Android and I'm trying to do one thing, but I'm not sure if I can or I can't do it.

My problem is this: I'm parsing a Json and I send this json to my class. All is correct, json works and the data is stored correctly. That I want to do, is access to the data that I've stored in the arrayList from another class, but I don't know how to do it.

I've tried to implement a singleton java class, but I can't access to the data.

That I said is for exampl. If I create this method I can access to the data, but I need to pass the data from my json to the method.

```
 public String showOverlay(ArrayList<ScreenEvent> config){
        String show = "";
        String empty = "empty";
        for(ScreenEvent client : config){
            show = client.action;

            if(show.equals("show"))
                return show;
        }
        return empty;
    }
```

I don't want to do this. I want to be able to create an object of the arrayList inside of my method:

```
 public String myMethod(){

         //I want access here to the data of the arrayList

            return empty;
        }
```

I read a json and pass the data in a ArrayList:

```
    public static ArrayList<VsClientConfig.ScreenEvent> eventConfig = new ArrayList<VsClientConfig.ScreenEvent>();

       //JSON stuff
       VsClientConfig.ScreenEvent vs = VsClientConfig.ScreenEvent.getScreenEvent(action, className, typeEvent, viewId, colourEvent);
       eventConfig.add(vs);
```

This is my class:

```
public class VsClientConfig{

    public String colour;
    public String height;

    public static class ScreenEvent {
        public String action;
        public String className;
        public String typeEvent;
        public String viewId;
        public String colourEvent;
        private static ScreenEvent miScreenEvent;

        public static ScreenEvent getScreenEvent(String action, String className, String typeEvent, String viewId, String colourEvent) {

            if (miScreenEvent == null) {

                miScreenEvent = new ScreenEvent(action, className, typeEvent, viewId, colourEvent);
            }
            return miScreenEvent;
        }

        private ScreenEvent(String action, String className, String typeEvent, String viewId, String colourEvent) {
            this.action = action;
            this.className = className;
            this.typeEvent = typeEvent;
            this.viewId = viewId;
            this.colourEvent = colourEvent;
        }

    }

    public String myMethod(){

     //I want access here to the data of the arrayList

        return empty;
    }
...
```

Comment: Is your ArrayList in the singleton class?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047775/how-to-access-arraylist-from-another-class-in-android-java

Comment: @miles Not sure.... This is the code that I have...

Comment: Just write a getter that returns the list. If you need to pass it to another activity, you'll need to make it Parcelable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create and initialize static arrayList in a Common class like below:

```
public class Common{
       public static ArrayList<VsClientConfig.ScreenEvent> eventConfig=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And assign if from wherever you want like:

```
//JSON stuff
       VsClientConfig.ScreenEvent vs = VsClientConfig.ScreenEvent.getScreenEvent(action, className, typeEvent, viewId, colourEvent);
       Common.eventConfig.add(vs);
```

Now **Common.eventConfig** (your arrayList) will be accessible to through your application